# the assembly reference (exception from haresult:0x80131040)

Tags: excel, excepciones, itextsharp, assembly

Primero que todo soy un novato en la programación y en la empresa a la que ingrese a trabajar hace poco me pidieron que arreglara este problema
en el momento de abrir el archivo de Excel se emite un mensaje de alerta con el siguiente error:

> unhandled exception has ocurred in your applicatiom. if you click
> continue.the application will ignore this error and attemp to
> continue.if you click to quit trhe application close immediately.
> could not load file or aseembly 'itestsharp'.
> version=5.2.10,cultrure=nuetral,publick key token=8354ae6d2174ddca or
> one of its dependencies. the located assembly's manifest definition
> not match  the assembly reference (exception from
> haresult:0x80131040).

Lo extraño es que este error solo aparece en ocasiones y hay algunos archivos que si los permite generar y abrir

La imagen que sale con el error es la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tiene pinta de estar relacionado con un add-in o complemento que se carga al abrir esos archivos. ¿Qué extensión tienen?  ¿Miraste el libro de macros personal? ¿Qué dicen los detalles?

Comment: aun no se que dicen los detalles ya que este es la unica documentacion que me dieron del problema debido a que se encuentra instalado ya en produccion y no se puede obtener acceso pero si me dices que necesito lo puedo conseguir y subirlo adjunto a la pregunta